# Show AdMob screen instead of Loading image on iOS

Tags: ios, admob

Is there way to show ads screen as a default screen when app is loading?

I have checked AdMob SDK and there is one method how to achieve this in app delegate, but seems ads start to display just after loading screen in my case.

So if I can show ads instead of loading screen so the problem is in my code as I understand.

Comment: As a user: please don't.

Comment: @Undo what do you mean? =)

Comment: as you can see here seems it has to work in my question 
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced#ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The loading screen is a static imageb and cannot be configured otherwise.

Quoting the docs (emphasis mine):

> Invoking loadAndDisplayRequest:usingWindow:initialImage: from within the app delegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: effectively queues an interstitial for display **the moment it isReady**. The initial image—typically the app's default—**remains onscreen until the load request either succeeds or fails.**

Also note that the ad only starts loading in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Comment: so as I think the method that allow to do it just for loading ads after default screen? am I right?

Please check the details here under Splash title

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced#ios